# Get Access to BluetoothDevices from Set

Tags: listview, bluetooth, set, onitemclick

I'm trying to establish a connection between Android and a Bluetooth module. I follow the instructions from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
after "Discovering" I placed the found Devices into a ListView, which has a registered `OnItemClickListener`.

My Problem now is that I need the `BluetoothDevice` from the clicked entry to establish the connection in the next step. All I have is a position ID in the ListView and a `Set<BluetoothDevice>`. But I don´t know how to extract the specific `BluetoothDevice` out of the Set.

This is my code so far.
Thanks!!

```java
ProgressBar spinWheel;
ListView devList;
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<String> lvAdapter;
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchlist);
    spinWheel = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    devList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.devicelist);
    lvAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.simplerow, R.id.simpleRow);
    devList.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
    devList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position,
                long id) {
            //establish Connection, need the clicked BluetoothDevice
        }
    });

    //gepaarte Geräte in die ListView
    pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    //If there are paired devices
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        // Loop through paired devices
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            lvAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"+ "#"+ device.getAddress());
        }
    }

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                lvAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                pairedDevices.add(device);
            }
        }
    };
    // Register the BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by myself, but I want to post it to help others.
I used the function BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(String adress).
As adress in inserted the String out of ListView, split at "#".

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position,
                long id) {
            String[] separated = lvAdapter.getItem(position).split("#");
            if(btAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(separated[1])==true){
            devtoconnect = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(separated[1]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Nevertheless Thanks for your help in other Questions!